# Vários if em uma condição SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if

Estou tentando usar 2 `if`s porém o resultado sempre retorna vazio, quando eu utilizo somente um `if` ele vai.

```
SELECT aci_codigo, aci_valor_pagamento, bai_fk_pes_codigo,
       aci_tipo_pagamento, aci_fk_ftm_codigo, aci_nosso_numero,
       ftm_descricao, ftm_codigo, bai_fk_bor_codigo, 
       bor_tipo,bai_data_cadastro
FROM acordo_item
INNER JOIN baixa ON bai_fk_aci_codigo = aci_codigo
INNER JOIN bordero ON bor_codigo = bai_fk_bor_codigo
LEFT JOIN financeiro_tipo_movimentacao ON ftm_codigo = aci_fk_ftm_codigo
WHERE aci_status = 'B'
AND 
IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = "PE", bai_data_cadastro, bor_data_criacao) >= '2016-11-22 00:00:00'
AND 
IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = "PE", bai_data_cadastro, bor_data_criacao) <= '2016-11-22 00:00:00'
GROUP BY aci_codigo
```

Comment: Qual é o objetivo da restrição por aci_tipo_pagamento? Observe que construiu algo como "A >= x and A <= x". A restrição somente será verdadeira se A = x. Isto é, somente se a data selecionada for 22/11/2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
AND 
(
IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = "PE", bai_data_cadastro, bor_data_criacao) >= '2016-11-22 00:00:00'
AND 
IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = "PE", bai_data_cadastro, bor_data_criacao) <= '2016-11-22 00:00:00'
)
GROUP BY aci_codigo
```

Comment: Como é que estes parêntesis resolvem o problema???

Comment: Mas resolveram ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira

AND  IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = 'PE', bai_data_cadastro >= '{$dataI} 00:00:00', bor_data_criacao >= '{$dataI} 00:00:00') 
                AND  IF(aci_tipo_pagamento = 'PE', bai_data_cadastro <= '{$dataF} 23:59:59', bor_data_criacao <= '{$dataF} 23:59:59')